# query for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with no primary-foreign key relationship. I want to delete a record(row to be more specific) in Table1 when count of a row in Table2 reaches a certain value.

```
Table1
ID      Name
1       name1
2       name2

Table2
ID     Name     Country
1      name1     US
2      name2     China
3      name2     Germany
4      name1     KSA
```

If name1 count in Table2 reaches 40 then delete name1 from Table1

Hope i have explained it all.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you please provide few rows from the tables and the output you need.

Comment: You can look into trigger. Perform the required logic in the INSERT trigger

Comment: @PawanKumar rows are almost same as in this example. Data type of Name column is nvarchar.

Comment: @Squirrel Im fairly new in sql server.could you please guide me how to achieve this objective?

Comment: @ImrePühvel All i did so far is got COUNT of rows in Table2 for each name (i.e name1 10,name2 7 etc). I dont know how to delete name1 row in Table1 if it reaches 40 rows in Table2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well you need `DELETE` with `JOIN`; In the sub-query you get the count / name and then join to `table1` and `DELETE` where count reaches the limit you want.

```
DELETE T1
FROM tbl1 T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        name
        ,COUNT(name) as cnt
    FROM tbl2
    GROUP BY name
)T2
    ON T1.name = T2.name
WHERE cnt >= 40
```

**Edit**: I added some sample data [**here**](http://rextester.com/HAP65192) for you test the code.

Comment: I tried this solution but i think there is some syntax issue here. DELETE T1 is invalid object. Could you look into this whats wrong

DELETE WorkShop.WorkshopName
FROM Workshop
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        workshopname
        ,COUNT(workshopname) as cnt
    FROM WorkshopOrders
    GROUP BY WorkshopName
)WorkshopOrders
    ON Workshop.WorkshopName = WorkshopOrders.WorkshopName
WHERE cnt >= 10

Comment: You don't need to put the column name before `DELETE` statement; just leave the table name (or use aliases as in my code);

Comment: sorry about the mess..i dont know how to format it here as i'm new on this forum.

Comment: I tested with table name and it executed but 0 rows affected. one workshop have 10 orders but query didnt delete in Table1 :(

Comment: because condition is to delete over 40?

Comment: I changed it to 10 for testing...plz see above code cnt>=10

Comment: @IrfanAhmed mate the query should work, apart from the fact that you need to delete the column name after `DELETE` statement it's ok. I also edit the answer and I added a link to test it with sample data. This is your query, corrected, `DELETE WorkShop FROM Workshop INNER JOIN ( SELECT workshopname ,COUNT(workshopname) as cnt FROM WorkshopOrders GROUP BY WorkshopName )WorkshopOrders ON Workshop.WorkshopName = WorkshopOrders.WorkshopName WHERE cnt >= 10`

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood I came up with this solution. I'm not sure how efficient this is but I guess does the trick.

```
DELETE FROM Table1 where Name IN (select Name from Table2 group by [Name] having count(Name)>=40)
```

Edit: Here you SQL Fiddle that you can try with small set of data.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9bf70/21

Comment: I have tested your query. Delete part is not working but Select is giving correct results.

Comment: It might be SQL Fiddle because I tried it on a local database and it's deleted the results that it supposed to.

Comment: may be it works with one table. Could you try with 2 tables as in my scenario?

Comment: I think you are closest to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use stored procedure.

```
Create Procecedure DeleteRecords
(
@recCount int,
@nameField varchar(20)
)
Begin
 If((select count(id) from Table2 where [name]=@nameField) >= @recCount)
begin
 Delete from Table1 where [name]=@nameField
end
End
```

Answer (score 0):

You create the `INSERT` trigger on `Table2`

```
create trigger ti_Table2 ON Table2 for insert
as
begin

    -- delete rows from table1
    delete  t1
    from
    (
        -- here it get list of name that exceeds 40 rows
        select  i.Name
        from    (
                    -- get the distinct Name 
                    -- inserted contains newly inserted rows
                    select  distinct i.Name
                    from    inserted i
                ) i
                -- join it to Table2 to find no of rows
                inner join Table2 t2    on  i.Name  = t2.Name
        group by i.Name
        having count(*) >= 40    -- when exceed 40
    ) t2
    inner join Table1 t1    on  t2.Name     = t1.Name

end
```